# How to provide X509KeyStorageFlags to CertificateRequest

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

It is possible to specify X509KeyStorageFlags in X509Certificate2 constructor what would look like this:

```
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

But in my case I use CertificateRequest to create self signed certificate so I do not have a certificate constructor:

```
var rsaKeyPair = RSA.Create();
var request = new CertificateRequest(
                      $"cn = {Environment.MachineName}",
                      rsaKeyPair,
                      HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                      RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs);

request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment |
                                          X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, true));

var certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow),
                                           new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(2)));
```

Is there a way to add KeyStorageFags to request.CertificateExtension or something like that?

Comment: There is a constructor :  public X509Certificate2 (byte[] rawData, string password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)

Comment: Key options should be passed to the key object: `var rsaKeyPair = RSA.Create();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to provide X509KeyStorageFlags to CertificateRequest

CertificateRequest doesn't understand anything about key storage.  All it does is build the certificate, then call `cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(privateKey)`.

Moving the target:

> How to provide X509KeyStorageFlags to CopyWithPrivateKey

CopyWithPrivateKey copies the key in its current state.  Ephemeral keys stay ephemeral.  Persisted keys stay persisted.

Moving the target:

> How to provide X509KeyStorageFlags to RSA.Create()

RSA.Create() always creates ephemeral keys, it doesn't understand key storage at all.  You'd have to use a specific RSA implementation that understands persistence -- but that then locks you into Windows (of course, you could have your calling code vary on OS).

```
RSA rsaKeyPair = BuildMachinePersistedKeyPair(2048);

...

private static RSA BuildMachinePersistedKeyPair(int keySize)
{
    CngKeyCreationParameters creationParameters = new CngKeyCreationParameters()
    {
        ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.Exportable,
        Provider = CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider,
        KeyCreationOptions =
            CngKeyCreationOptions.OverwriteExistingKey |
            CngKeyCreationOptions.MachineKey,
    };

    CngProperty keySizeProperty = new CngProperty(
        KeyPropertyName.Length,
        BitConverter.GetBytes(keySize),
        CngPropertyOptions.None);

    creationParameters.Parameters.Add(keySizeProperty);

    using (CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), creationParameters))
    {
        return new RSACng(cngKey);
    }
}
```

> Is there an easier way?

Sure, just export/import the ephemeral one.

```
X509Certificate2 certificate;

using (X509Certificate2 ephemeral = request.CreateSelfSigned(...))
{
    certificate = new X509Certificate2(
        ephemeral.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12),
        string.Empty,
        X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
}
```

Comment: So I went with what you referred as easy way. And what happens is `request.CreateSelfSigned()` creates certificate(1 allocation) than calls returns `certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(key)` (2 allocation) than I call `new X509Certificate(cert, password, keys)` that return desired certificate object (3 allocation).
Well thats basically why I asked the question. I thought of `CreateSelfSigned()` as my builder function and though I do it wrong cause I can't communicate desired object in one go. But as it turns out it doesn't work that way.
Thx